# tooltip in mobile not working material2

Tags: angular-material2

the tooltip are not working in mobile devices.

```
 mdTooltip="message" [mdTooltipPosition]="tooltipPosition"
```

when I hover the the div that contain the code it's working on desktop 
I know that on mobile I have to click but the click is not working.

Comment: long press on element and try. it should work.

Comment: how I can use  Shows/hides the tooltip like a toggle?

Comment: For me, It's working in chrome mobile version. you just need to long press on an element, then the tooltip will be visible and to hide tap anywhere on the screen. and yes one more thing update your angular material. in latest update you have to change all tags I.e, replace `md` with `mat`

Comment: Yes I have to update, how I can change the delay, I want to do a normal press and then the pop up appear not a long press.
Many thank's.

Comment: If there is no such functionality is associated with your element then it'll work on single touch.

Answer (score 1):

My solution in Angular:

```
<button #tooltip="matTooltip" (click)="tooltip.toggle()" matTooltip="text" matTooltipPosition="above" aria-label="Button that shows a tooltip"> Tooltip </button>
```

use `(click)="tooltip.toggle()"` with `#tooltip="matTooltip"`